# What is the best practice for comparing against the current time in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In the app I'm working on we compare against Time.now in some places, and Database.time in others. I would like to use only one of these throughout the whole application. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find much information on them through google searches. Which is preferred? How are they different from each other? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of articles on thoughtbot's blog that cover this:

- https://robots.thoughtbot.com/its-about-time-zones
- https://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-case-study-in-multiple-time-zones

Hopefully those help.

Answer (score 0):

The function `Time.now` gives you the time in the application server running your Rails app request. This is reliable in most cases.

Rails uses the app server time when filling the `updated_at` and `created_at` columns of its models.

I'm not sure about the `Database.time` function you are referring to... This is probably a class defined in your code or inherited from gem in your app. Because of that I would suggest moving to the Ruby core time functions. In your case: `Time.now`